# Turn void method into a boolean-java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'd like to make this into a boolean that will return true or false.
I simply got no idea how to , so I need some help.

```
public static void checkUSPASS(String a,String b) {
    try {
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            String sql;
          sql = "SELECT * FROM db Where Email='"+a+"' and Password='"+b+"'";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          if(rs.next())
               {
               //return true 
               }
           else 
                {
                 //return false
                }

        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); }

        }
```

I should probably get all declarations out , but I'd like to hear what do you think guys.

Comment: What do you mean with "get all declarations out"?

Comment: @dotvav part between "try" and "if(rs.next())" , that probably shouldn't be inside a boolean  , but i'm not sure .

Comment: `boolean` is a primitive type, and you can't put anything inside a `boolean` except a `true` or `false`. The code you are showing is a method. You can change the return type of the method, and put whatever you like in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the method signature to return a value:

```
public static boolean checkUSPASS(String a,String b)
```

Then return a value from within the method:

```
return true;
```

or:

```
return false;
```

Note that all code paths must return some value.  So you have this in your `try` block:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

But in the event of reaching your `catch` block, something must still be returned:

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: give me a few minutes to try this :) , thanks it advance .

Comment: all code paths must either return a value, **or throw an exception**

Comment: @dotvav: True, an exception is a valid exit condition for a method.  But this method doesn't declare a `throws` clause.  That change can also be made to the method signature, if the OP wishes.

Comment: that's it , I figured it out . Worked !

Comment: @David that is only true for checked exceptions. If you throw any exception that extends `RuntimeException` you will not need to modify the method signature.

Answer (score 3):

While this is not the answer to your question, but I believe it will help you to make your method better. Probably comment will be more suitable, but comments with large piece of text are hard to read.

[Don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) use SQL query string composition like you do. Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of that.

Process exceptions inside of your method or throw them further. Printing stack trace **is not** the exception processing, it hides the problem from the end-user.

To throw the exception further add `throws SQLException` to your method declaration, and remove try/catch construction from the method body. It will allow the caller to process the exception and will avoid many hard-to-catch bugs later.

Don't store passwords as Strings, it is a bad practice. [Hash passwords with salt](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) and store password hashcode.

And finally your method declaration should look like that:

```
public static boolean checkUSPASS(String username,String hashCode) throws SQLException
```

Comment: You are right about it , but this is just some small project , nothing really serious. Thank you , I will read that about hash password for further use in future +1.

Comment: I think it is important to get into the right habits when you are learning and dealing with small projects. Later it pay back with stable and maintenable code, when you work on bigger projects.

Answer (score 0):

To change a function to `boolean` in java all you have to do is change `void` to `boolean` in your function definition and return true or false at all end points.

Comment: I agree , I'm not a smart man , I think I'm about to solve this stupid question . My apologies ! :)